# Create MQTT Broker if one isn't present on network with Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt

I have to build a modular system where each system could run by itself, or if they are connected to the same network, they could work together. Each system would have a **raspberry pi** that could potentially run an **MQTT broker** to handle messaging from other components in the system.

But I am wondering if I connect more than one system to the same network, is there a method to figure out if a broker is already present and disregard spinning up another broker so the 2nd system introduced to the network would use the first systems broker?

Comment: You could maybe use `avahi-utils` to advertise your MQTT service and then `avahi-browse -r _mqtt._tcp` to see if it's present.

Comment: This should get you started... https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/discussions/11403

Comment: Amazing. This sounds promising. I'll look into it! Thanks for the link